# MySQL query extracted to csv, but information is not in proper rows

Tags: mysql, csv, extract

I have written a query in MySQL and extracted it to a csv file.
The problem I have is that the values from the 3rd and 4th are not next to the values from the 1st and 2nd column, but one row below them.

```
SELECT * FROM KSK_Age2
INTO OUTFILE "C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Uploads\\kskAge.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This is the sql code I used to extract the query result. And I am also attaching a screenshot of the extraction in csv.

Thanks in advance!
[image: Screenshot of the distorted data]

Comment: CSV is text file - so show it in some text editor, not after importing into the excel workbook. Additionally - provide CREATE TABLE for source table and 2-3 dumped rows.

Comment: When I open the file a text editor I see the same result.
To be honest I don't know what dumped rows mean.

The queries I have used:
**To create the KSK_in_pick table:
`CREATE TABLE KSK_in_pick(
SKU VARCHAR(20),
lot INT,
Location VARCHAR(7),
PRIMARY KEY(SKU)
);`


`CREATE TABLE Inv_Transactions (
ID INT,
SKU VARCHAR(15),
Fromloc VARCHAR(7),
Fromid VARCHAR(20),
Toloc VARCHAR(7),
DateAdded DATE,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);`

`CREATE TABLE KSK_Age AS
SELECT ksk.SKU, Location, inv.DateAdded
FROM KSK_in_pick ksk
JOIN inv_transactions inv
ON ksk.SKU = inv.SKU;`

Comment: *I don't know what dumped rows mean* Create temporary database. Copy the table into it. Copy 2-3 rows into the table. Dump this database. Open the dump as text, provide CERATE TABLE and INSERT INTO from it.